# Server change ip with nodejs - axios post or get

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

my server have 10 ip adress.

İp list
109.232.220.2
109.232.220.3
109.232.220.4
109.232.220.5
109.232.220.6
...

How to use axios get or post with other ips on Nodejs ?

Comment: with requests you can use `http://1.2.3.4/...` instead of `http://example.com/...`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone my site send api requests. But api have req limit. I want to use other ip addresses.

Comment: oh, you want to bind the outgoing request to a particular IP address - I misunderstood, since you never mentioned that

Comment: are you found real solution ? @CanerDumanoğlu

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution working both with https and IPV6

```
const https = require('https');

const getWrappedHttpsTransport = ({
  localAddress,
  ...forceOptions
} = {}) => ({
  ...https,
  request: (options, callback) => https.request({
    ...options,
    ...forceOptions,
    ...localAddress && {
      localAddress,
      family: localAddress.includes(':') ? 6 : 4,
    },
  }, callback),
});
```

Use it like that :

```
const instance = axios.create({
  transport: getWrappedHttpsTransport({
    localAddress,
  }),
});

instance.get('/url');
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not understandable for me like you. It is possible to provide an example with more details

Comment: Hi @Kiax axios.create will give you an axios instance => const instance = axios.create

Use this instance like you would use axios itself => instance.get('/url')

I updated my answer so :)

Answer (score -1):

Reposting a similar answer that does not require you to create a new Axios instance - you can simply change the IP on each call.

from Axios' Github here:
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2025#issuecomment-877599901

```
// Setup connection parameters:
const https = require('https')
const ip = 'X.X.X.X'  // either IPv4 or IPv6 address
const options = { 
  localAddress: ip,
  family: ip.includes(':') ? 6 : 4  // detect if IPv6
}
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent(options)

// Use it:
axios.get('https://example.com/', { httpsAgent })
```

Can change https to http if needed.

I've used and tested this myself and it works as expected to bind your calls to a specific IP.